# Assigning a variable of type class to a different class that extends the declared variable type

Tags: java, android

So I have declared this:

```
Class<ThemeControls> thisClass = ThemeControls.class;
```

I would like to access the methods and variables within this class through a separate class that extends `ThemeControls`. This class:

```
public class BaseControls extends ThemeControls { ... }
```

An error this thrown when using this line of code:

```
thisClass = BaseControls.class;
```

Error:

`Incompatible types`

Since BaseContols extends ThemeControls, it can be declared as the same type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Class<BaseControls>` is not exact `Class<ThemeControls>`. You need to use `Class<? extends ThemeControls>`.

So:

```
Class<? extends ThemeControls> thisClass =  BaseControls.class;;
```

Comment: Brilliant as soon as I found this you answered. Will test, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This must work for you:

```
Class<? extends ThemeControls> thisClass =...
```